# Android Static title bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create an app that when you click through each page of the app the title bar doesn't move. I can create an xml with the same title bar but every time you go on to a new page the title bar disappears for a second and then reappears with the new page.

Does anybody have any suggestions/code that can help me with this?

Many Thanks

Comment: I assume you have separate Activities with a shared header layout? If that isn't working for you could you use a single Activity instead and swap out the rest of the layout as you click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). If you implement "each page of the app" as a separate [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) - instead of `Activity` - then you can embed and switch these `Fragment`s into the layout of the main Activity, obtaining what you need.

Comment: So you have 1 page and bring everything it to that page ie into a list view?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `tabActivity` and have the activities inside it.

hide the tab bar as given here [tab bar hiding issue android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987596/tab-bar-hiding-issue-android)

Use `mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag` to set the tab